# database column with datatype bit is not getting updated using java code

Tags: java, sql-server-2008

I have one value as string say '1'.
I need to put this in column whose data type is bit.
I am trying to update this value using wraaper class as Boolean by typecasting(e.g. like (Boolean)map.key("key_name") as well as by parsing like (Boolean.parseBoolean(map.key("key_name").toString())

But its not updating. I am using  MS sql server 2008.

Comment: Post your corresponding source code!

Answer (score 0):

BIT datatype can only store either **0 or 1**. It can't store BOOLEAN values that is **TRUE** or **FLASE**. Here you will need to convert you TRUE or FALSE value to 1 or 0 respectively to store it into BIT column.